# Listas de tamaño variable en C

Tags: c, lista

soy nuevo en C y se me presenta el siguiente problema:

quiero crear listas con un tamaño variable a las que pueda ir agregando o eliminando elementos, sin tener que definir un tamaño predeterminado al crearla.

Comment: Y la pregunta es...? Lee [ask].

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Una buena pregunta siempre termina reabierta :)

Answer (score 0):

agregas un * antes de tu variable ejemplo:

```
char* mivariable
```

y usas [malloc](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc) para verificar reservar mas memoria para los nuevos elementos.

Referencias:
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc

https://www.uco.es/grupos/eatco/informatica/metodologia/cadenasyarrays.pdf

https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-arrays

https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/cya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=37&codigo=37&inicio=30